# How to type blank character with Mac keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard

One can type blank character (no visible output but not <kbd>Space</kbd>) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+255 on the numpad.

I want to know how to type blank text in Mac.

Comment: Those are not blanktext but another form of space - what is the end result you need?

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd> is a non-breakable space (well known as `&nbsp;` in HTML).

On OS X, you can get it with <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: But they aren't the same

Comment: @TomGewecke, By using windows' Alt+255 it was possible to post on Twitter or Telegram, but by using the above answer it's not possible on macOS, if you follow my answer you can find it possible to post on Twitter and Telegram

Comment: @TomGewecke, leave me alone.